# IIB - execution group sufficient disk space

Tags: ibm-integration-bus

I'm setting up a new IBM Integration Bus server and am working to deploying BAR files to an execution group and receive a "sufficient disk space" type error message when trying to deploy multiple BAR's to the execution group, but when deploying the same BAR to an empty execution group it succeeds. This happens with multiple BAR files and on multiple servers. It's very repeatable. I feel I'm missing a configuration step on IIB for these execution groups. I should mention this configuration type worked on IBM MB 6.1 - I've got the exact same java code, just upgrading the platform from MB to IIB. I see this error message when googling and searching ibm's kb but never a solution.

Below is a snip-it of the error message. Does anyone see what I'm missing?? Any help greatly appreciated.

> While attempting to process an administration request, an exception
>   was encountered. No updates have been made to the configuration of the
>   integration server.
>
> Review related error messages to determine why the administration
>   request failed.
>
> BIP4502E: An unexpected error occurred during the deployment of a Java
>   resource.
>
> An error occurred during the deployment of a Java resource. This may
>   have left the integration node in an inconsistent state.
>
> Ensure there is sufficient disk space available on the machine running
>   the integration node runtime. Stop the integration node, delete all
>   files in
>   'C:\ProgramData\IBM\MQSI\components\DEV_BKR\d66dcf37-79e3-4693-860d-b6de38df08d0\config\JAR\',
>   restart the integration node and perform a full redeploy.
>
> BIP4395E: Java exception: 'java.nio.file.FileSystemException'; thrown
>   from class name: 'sun.nio.fs.WindowsException', method name:
>   'translateToIOException', file: 'WindowsException.java', line: '99'
>
> The message contains that data associated with a Java exception.

Comment: I don't know if you already did resolve your problem, if not, have a look at this post: http://www.mqseries.net/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?t=29923

Answer (score 0):

Try to cleanup the execution group working directory. This can be found under the ApplicationData directory in your user folder if you are using a Windows platform.
As a good practice, try to uninstall all applications and libraries from the execution group before manually removing all files from the working directory.